# How to share vendor for mutiple projects in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to use vendor folder as common for my multiple set of projects.
I have added the following lines in composer.json files,

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "vendor-dir":"/../vendor"
}

"psr-4": {
    "ProjectRoot\\" : "", 
    "NamspaceInSourceDir\\" : "myApp/"         
}
```

and change the vendor folder path in autoload.php.

but still fatal errors and warning messages are displaying,

> Warning:
>   include(D:\workspace\sss\laravel\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\workspace\sss\laravel\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 440
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist' in
>   D:\workspace\sss\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 749
>
> ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist in
>   D:\workspace\sss\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 749

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's definitely not recommended. But definitely possible to share Vendor directory between serveral laravel projects as long as they all use the same dependencies. What kind of OS are you using?

Comment: The correct way to "share" a vendor directory between two projects would be to duplicate the composer.json file verbatim. If exact versions of vendor files are required, define your version for each include explicitly. Other than saving a few MB of storage space on your computer, there would be no other benefit (unless you are editing the vendor files manually, which goes against the whole concept of composer). Please let us know more about what you're trying to do.